# Ajax Calender Extender issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i have textbox in which i want to store the selected date of calender. for this purpose i have used [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) calender extender. and set the target control property to textbox id. but when i click on button of same page then i lost the seleted date (i mean i lost the textvalue) but i want to the selected date after clicking on button..
my code is as

```
<td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
 <td>
     <asp:ImageButton ID="imgCalender" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.png" ToolTip="Select a Date" />
   <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calShow"  runat="server" PopupButtonID="imgCalender" PopupPosition="BottomLeft" TargetControlID="txtDate" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="CheckForPastDate"></asp:CalendarExtender>
  </td>
```

and also i want when user try to select a date which is greater than the current date+20 days then text box should be empty. means user have to select again a proper date.

#### Javascript

```
var selectedDate = new Date(); 
selectedDate = sender._selectedDate; 
var todayDate = new Date(); 

if (selectedDate.getDateOnly() <= todayDate.getDateOnly()) 
{
    alert('Date Cannot be in the past or current date'); 
    sender._textbox.set_Value(null); 
} 
else if(selectedDate.getDateOnly() > todayDate.getDateOnly()) 
{
     // why is this here?
}
```

Comment: I think the `ReadOnly` attribute is your issue.

Comment: thanks it working fine .. but i don't want user to insert the date in textbox manually, this is the reason i have set readonly property true.is there another way to do this

Comment: use `CSS` to disable the textbox instead? 
As for your other query about checking the date, would you not just handled that within the "CheckForPastDate" function?

Comment: i didn't get you "CheckForPastDate" function? 
will you please explain?

Comment: within the markup you have posted you have a `OnClientDateSelectionChanged` event being handled, I assume there is a `JavaScript` method which is handling this event.

Comment: my js fun is 
var selectedDate = new Date();
            selectedDate = sender._selectedDate;
            var todayDate = new Date();
            if (selectedDate.getDateOnly() <= todayDate.getDateOnly())
            {
                alert('Date Cannot be in the past or current date');
                sender._textbox.set_Value(null);
                
            }
            else if(selectedDate.getDateOnly() > todayDate.getDateOnly())
            {
                
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within the js method just do something like

```
var today = new Date();
var twentyDays = new Date();
twentyDays.setDate(today.getDate()+20);

if (selectedDate.getDateOnly() <= todayDate.getDateOnly()) 
{
    alert('Date Cannot be in the past or current date'); 
    sender._textbox.set_Value(null); 
} 
else if(selectedDate.getDateOnly() > twentyDays.getDateOnly()) 
{
    alert('this is more than 20 days');
    sender._textbox.set_Value(null); 
    return;
}
```

**Update** 02/12/2013

I am not sure what the getDateOnly() method is or does and that seemed to be causing me issues.
The script below is what I put together to test scenarios and works. simply adjust the `daysModifier` variable to test.

```
var daysModifier = 23;
var selectedDate = new Date();
selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate() + daysModifier);

var today = new Date();
var twentyDays = new Date();
twentyDays.setDate(today.getDate()+20);

document.write(today);
document.write("<br />");
document.write(selectedDate);
document.write("<br />");
document.write(twentyDays);


if (selectedDate <= today) 
{
    alert('Date cannot be in the past or current date'); 
} 
else if(selectedDate > twentyDays) 
{
    alert('this is more than 20 days');
}
```

Comment: after adding  this line twentyDays.setDate(today.getDate()+20); java script stop comparing the date . after this line it won't even compare the past dates

Comment: @AmitKumar added an update, hope this will help resolve your issue